# how long Google Fitness keeps data?

Tags: fitness

I made an appliction using Google Fitness and wanna know how long Google Fitness keeps data. (ex. User's step counts, heart rate, activity ...)

thanks.

I checked the privacy policy of Google but couldn't figure out.

Answer (score 0):

> Google stores data of all activities unless you remove it from your log.

- Methods to remove Google fitness data

> For Android phones:

```
Delete your Google Fit data

    On your Android phone, open the Google Fit app Google Fit.
    At the bottom, tap Profile.
    At the top, tap Settings Settings.
    Tap Manage your data.
    Tap More  and then "Delete All."
    Confirm you want to delete the data.

Deleting your history only removes saved information from your Google Account. Other apps or devices might have similar data stored in their own services. If you want to delete that information, you’ll need to use their settings.
```

> For iPhone phones:

```
Delete your Google Fit data

    On your iPhone, open the Google Fit app Google Fit.
    At the bottom, tap Profile.
    At the top, tap Settings Settings.
    Tap Manage your data.
    Tap More  and then "Delete All."
    Confirm you want to delete the data.

Deleting your history only removes saved information from your Google Account. Other apps or devices might have similar data stored in their own services. If you want to delete that information, you’ll need to use their settings.
```